# InnoSetup: If no components are selected, go back to components page

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to write a pascal function in InnoSetup, requiring the user to select at least one component before proceeding. This works, but seems a little dirty. Is there another way of doing this?

I've found absolutely no documentation on how to check if **any** components are selected.

My code is as follows:

```
function NextButtonClick(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result:= True;
  if PageID = wpSelectComponents then begin
    S := FmtMessage('%1', [WizardSelectedComponents(false)]);
    if S = '' then begin
      MsgBox('No items selected, please select at least one item', mbError, MB_OK);
      Result := False;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've shown seems to be the shortest available at this time (though I don't feel much confident about it, as well as you). The only alternative I can think of is to iterate the `ComponentsList` and see if at least one item returns `Checked` property as True:

```
[Code]
function IsAnyComponentSelected: Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  for I := 0 to WizardForm.ComponentsList.Items.Count - 1 do
    if WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[I] then
    begin
      Result := True;
      Exit;
    end;
end;
```

There is no `CheckedCount` like property for the `ComponentsList` nor any direct function for this sort of thing at this time, so this looks to me like a reliable alternative of course unless you use radio buttons, where may always be one option selected. In such cases you'd need to extend the above code of a way to determine the kind of the item and check the state only for check box type items.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. I wound up calling `IsAnyComponentSelected` in `NextButtonClick`, and it works flawlessly.